# Spring HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring

I have a form which a user is to use to upload a file to a local drive and also persist some data to the database. But this error message has come up which I would like to know how to deal with it.

```
   HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

The controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main/user/setter/addpage", method = 

RequestMethod.POST, params = "save")
public String saveProcess(@ModelAttribute("module") Module module, 

@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId, 
@RequestParam("name") String name,
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, 
BindingResult result, HttpSession session) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/main/user/setter/settingpage";
    }
    else
    if(module != null){

         try {

             MultipartFile filea = module.getFileData();

             InputStream inputStream = null;
             OutputStream outputStream = null;
             if (filea.getSize() > 0) {
             inputStream = filea.getInputStream();
             outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Test\\"
             + filea.getOriginalFilename());
             System.out.println("Uploaded File Name");
             System.out.println(filea.getOriginalFilename());
                             int readBytes = 0;
             byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
             while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != 

                             -1) {
             outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
             }
             outputStream.close();
             inputStream.close();
             session.setAttribute("success", "File Uploaded");
             session.setAttribute("uploadFile", "C:\\Test\\"
             + filea.getOriginalFilename());
             }
             } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             }

}
// Delegate to service
moduleService.add(userId, module);

return "redirect:/main/user/setter/settingpage";
    }
```

The form itself

```
 <c:url var="processUrl" value="/main/user/setter/addpage?userId=2" />
 <form:form modelAttribute="module" method="POST" action="${processUrl}" name="module" 

 enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <form:label path="fileName">Document Title:</form:label>
 <form:input path="fileName" name="name"/><br/>

 <form:label path="documentPath">Coursework Sample:</form:label>
 <form:input path="documentPath" type="file" name="file" id="file" size="43.9"/><br/>

 <form:label path="liveDate">Live Date:</form:label>
 <form:input path="liveDate"/><br/>

  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" id="save"/>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" id="send"/>

 </form:form>
```

I'm trying to save the form first the I will use a separate method to send it.

Comment: Can you perform the same request with the DEBUG method, or set up a http://requestb.in and add the actual request to the question.

Comment: I set up a requestb.in and tested it. It returned the correct page. The logic of the method is throwing up the error.

Comment: Move your `BindingResult` object in the method argument list to be next to the object it's related to, possibly `Module`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you that solved the incorrect syntax problem.

Comment: @user2259555 Do you have other errors popping up?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis care to add it as an answer so it can be useful for other users? Thanks!

Comment: @ssedano Added answer + reference.

Answer (score 9):

Your method is declared as such:

```
public String saveProcess(@ModelAttribute("module") Module module, 
@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId, 
@RequestParam("name") String name,
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, 
BindingResult result, HttpSession session) ...
```

Assuming that you are trying to apply the `BindingResult` to the `Module` instance, you need to change the method definition so that the `BindingResult` comes right after the `Module` instance.

```
public String saveProcess(@ModelAttribute("module") Module module,  
BindingResult result,
@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId, 
@RequestParam("name") String name,
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, 
HttpSession session) ...
```

See the reference for more details

> The Errors or BindingResult parameters have to follow the model object
>   that is being bound immediately as the method signature might have
>   more that one model object and Spring will create a separate
>   BindingResult instance for each of them [...]

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error `HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.` can come from a missing `multipartResolver` in the context (`servlet-context.xml`)

```
`<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />`
```

For more info, see the replies from [SpringMVC-FileUpload - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179118/springmvc-fileupload-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrec)