# SpringMVC-FileUpload - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I've seen couple of qts on the same topic. But I didn't find any clue of this error.

I am working on a POC and following the link below.
http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

As mentioned in the above tutorial, in standalone mode[spring embeded Tomcat] it is working absolutely fine.
But I want to deploy it as webapplication. So, I have created a separate SpringMVC project and added the following controller.

**Controller file**

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String provideUploadInfo() {
        return "You can upload a file by posting to this same URL.";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, 
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = 
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }

}
```

I've written the following client ( As I don't want to use RestTemplate here).

**Service Client**

```
private static final String URL_GET = "http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/upload";
static String URL = "http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/upload";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:/DevEnvProject/eclipse/workspace_exp/OCR/log4j.properties");
    testGet();
    testPOST();
}

private static void testGet() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL_GET);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String sResponse = reader.readLine();

} 

static void testPOST() {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        entity.addPart("name", new StringBody("testIcon.png"));
        entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File("C:/testIcon.png")));
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse = reader.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I couldn't make a successful call to the POST endpoint. Everytime, I'm getting the following exception.

**400 Bad Request - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect**

'GET' call is working fine. I compared the the log of the 'POST' request with the same 'POST' request which I got while testing with standalone approach as mentioned in the spring tutorial. Didn't find any diff in the request part.

I know that I'm quite verbose in this post. I wanted to give as much context info as possible. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: try to remove `@ResponseBody` from your controller and see.

Comment: @aman That won't affect the request coming in.

Comment: @Aman - thanks for reply. But that didn't help. Just now, I tried

Comment: Please set up logging for `org.springframework.web` package and check the output. Are you using Spring 3.2+?

Comment: No, I'm not using 3.2+ version. I'm using 3.0.5
yes, I enabled log and that helped. I was worried thinking something wrong in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to do:

First, add the Apache Commons FileUpload library to your class path. If you use maven, you can get the dependency [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3). If you don't, you can still download the jar and add it manually.

Second, you have to declare a `MultipartResolver` bean in your context with name `multipartResolver`. With Apache Commonds FileUpload, you can use `CommonsMultipartResolver`. For example, with Java config, that would be

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver(); 
    // set any fields
    return commonsMultipartResolver; 
}
```

With XML config,

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- set any properties -->
</bean>
```

This is further documented in the [Spring official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart).

Comment: Interesting, what `MultipartConfigElement`(class referenced created as bean in the tutorial) is supposed to do then? Look's like I need some refreshment :-)

Comment: @Boris See section 17.10.3 of the docs I linked. It's used for configuring how multipart requests are resolved in Servlet 3.0 environments. I have yet to use it. In my next app...

Comment: Thanks a lot Sotirios. I was clueless. It is all working now. I just added <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000" /> in the multipartResolver. Otherwise, image files were not getting uploaded. I need to spend some significant time on these. Thanks again.

Comment: @user19 You're welcome. The Spring documentation is extremely detailed if you have time to read it. Good luck!