# Spring MVC : POST and PUT not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, post, put

I am developing Spring MVC 4 Dynamic web module application.
In my application I have simple CRUD operations.
Get requests are working fine but POST and PUT are not working at all.
I am getting this error:
**HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**

This is my controller code for **GET**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCustomreById/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerDetails> getCustomer(
            @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        System.out.println(id);
        if (id != null)
            return new ResponseEntity<CustomerDetails>(
                    serv.getCustomerById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
        else
            return new ResponseEntity<CustomerDetails>(
                    serv.getCustomerById("1"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and for **POST** :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public int AddCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDetails customer) {
    return serv.addCustomer(customer);
}
```

**POST** Request :

```
{
    "customerName": "Sid",
    "customerEmail": "sid@gmail.com",
    "customerAddress": [{    
        "address1": "123 Street",
        "address2": " ",
        "zipCode": "400065",
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "state": "Maharashtra",
        "country": "India",
        "region": "Gateway of India"
    }]
}
```

I read on stackoverflow on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179118/springmvc-fileupload-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrec) question that I need to add multipart reosolver but even aafter adding that I am getting same error.

Comment: What is the request uri/url?

Comment: How are you sending the request. What is the client for this code?

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma  
Uri : http://localhost:8082/WebApp/customer/addCustomer
As of now there is no client code I am testing it on Rest Client for firfox.@VivekSingh

Comment: What is your **Content-Type** header of the request? Can you also post the classes **CustomerDetails** and **CustomerAddress**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just need to send `int` id as response, add `@ResponseBody` to the method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public int AddCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDetails customer) {
    return serv.addCustomer(customer);
}
```

Otherwise return `ResponseEntity` as you are doing for `GET`

```
return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(serv.addCustomer(customer), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: and why do you think so?

Comment: the issue he is recieving is `HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.` And something to do with the way the client is requesting the resource.

Comment: try implementing the code mentioned in the question without `@ResponseBody` you will be able to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Adding @ResponseBody will work for this question